# BotFramework: Start a Form from a Dialog using Intents

Tags: bots, botframework

Regarding the Microsoft Bot Framework, we all know the [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) given by Microsoft. Those samples, however, normally have "one single purpose", that is, the Pizzabot is only for ordering Pizzas, and so on.

Thing is, I was hoping on creating a more complex Bot that actually answers a series of things. For this I am creating a "lobby" dialog where all the messages go, using this MessageController:

```
 return await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new LobbyDialog());
```

On that "Lobby" dialog I have a series of LUIS intents for different things, and since it picks the Task based on the intent, it works nicely.

However, for more complex operations, I was hoping on using the FormFlow mechanism so I can have forms like in the PizzaBot sample. The problem is that all of the "form bots" that are sampled always use this message controller type:

```
return Chain.From(() => new PizzaOrderDialog(BuildForm)
```

And in the same MessagesController stablishes the builder flow, like this:

```
var builder = new FormBuilder<PizzaOrder>();

        ActiveDelegate<PizzaOrder> isBYO = (pizza) => pizza.Kind == PizzaOptions.BYOPizza;
        ActiveDelegate<PizzaOrder> isSignature = (pizza) => pizza.Kind == PizzaOptions.SignaturePizza;
        ActiveDelegate<PizzaOrder> isGourmet = (pizza) => pizza.Kind == PizzaOptions.GourmetDelitePizza;
        ActiveDelegate<PizzaOrder> isStuffed = (pizza) => pizza.Kind == PizzaOptions.StuffedPizza;

        return builder
            // .Field(nameof(PizzaOrder.Choice))
            .Field(nameof(PizzaOrder.Size))
            .Field(nameof(PizzaOrder.Kind))
            .Field("BYO.Crust", isBYO)
            .Field("BYO.Sauce", isBYO)
            .Field("BYO.Toppings", isBYO)
            .Field(nameof(PizzaOrder.GourmetDelite), isGourmet)
            .Field(nameof(PizzaOrder.Signature), isSignature)
            .Field(nameof(PizzaOrder.Stuffed), isStuffed)
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Confirm("Would you like a {Size}, {BYO.Crust} crust, {BYO.Sauce}, {BYO.Toppings} pizza?", isBYO)
            .Confirm("Would you like a {Size}, {&Signature} {Signature} pizza?", isSignature, dependencies: new string[] { "Size", "Kind", "Signature" })
            .Confirm("Would you like a {Size}, {&GourmetDelite} {GourmetDelite} pizza?", isGourmet)
            .Confirm("Would you like a {Size}, {&Stuffed} {Stuffed} pizza?", isStuffed)
            .Build()
            ;
```

My big question here is, is it possible to start the conversation with the MessagesController that I used and then in the LobbyDialog, use an Intent that fires a Form and returns it? That is, start a flow from a dialog? Or is better to use DialogChains for that?

Because, from what I tried, it appears that I can ONLY do forms if they are called from teh MessagesController class with the methods I described, that is, how Microsoft sampled it in the Pizzabot.

I appreciate any help or input on the matter. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can! Instantiating a form from a dialog is a pretty common scenario. To accomplish that you can do the following inside the LUIS intent method:

```
var form = new FormDialog<YourFormModel>(
                <ExistingModel>,
                <TheMethodThatBuildTheForm>,
                FormOptions.PromptInStart,
                result.Entities);

context.Call(form, <ResumeAfterCallback>);
```

using the PizzaBot sample, it should looks like:

```
var form = new FormDialog<PizzaOrder>(
                    null,
                    BuildForm,
                    FormOptions.PromptInStart,
                    result.Entities);

    context.Call(form, <ResumeAfterCallback>);
```

In the ResumeAfterCallback you will usually get the result of the form, catch exceptions and perform a context.Wait so the dialog can keep receiving messages. Below a quick example:

```
    private async Task ResumeAfterCallback(IDialogContext context, 
                                           IAwaitable<PizzaOrder> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var pizzaOrder = await result;
            // do something with the pizzaOrder

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
        catch (FormCanceledException<PizzaOrder> e)
        {
            string reply;

            if (e.InnerException == null)
            {
                 reply = "You have canceled the operation. What would you like to do next?";
            }
            else
            {
                  reply = $"Oops! Something went wrong :(. Technical Details: {e.InnerException.Message}";
            }

             await context.PostAsync(reply);
             context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you start the call from within an Intent and it rolls from there? Just one question, normally you call the Forms like this (as far as examples go): `return Chain.From(() => new PizzaOrderDialog(BuildForm));` but you are saying to use a context call, which I didn't though of and is awesome. My only question is: What do you "resumeaftercallback" if you are from within a Dialog?

Comment: Will depend on what your form does, but for sure you will have to do a context.Wait(this.MessageReceived); I updated the post with more information. Please mark it as an answer if it helps you.

Comment: Can you post your dialog please? The message controller just need to instantiate the LUIS dialog. That error is usually happening when a context.Wait is missing

Comment: (I posted another comment but the second I posted it tried something and it was a Wait after the call, sorry for wasting your time)
Thanks a lot! With your help I was able to figure out what was wrong and now is indenting the form in the conversation!. Un abrazo, ché ;)

Comment: Buenísimo! Mark it as answered please :) Abrazo